# Display data in a table in 3 columns, N number of rows

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm kinda stuck with this which might seem dumb at the moment.

I have a set of arrays which can have any number of elements can be from 6 to N

I can't modify the structure of the site right now, but it's made with a bootstrap responsive table. i need to display every element in the table but maximum 3 columns with N number of rows.

Like this

[image]

I did this in order to get the number of rows

```
$rows=ceil(count($array)/3);
```

Then i do a couple of for to display the table in that distribution

```
for( $i=0; $i<$rows; $i++ ) {
<tr>  
    for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
      <td>Value</td>
    }
</tr>
}
```

Until here all fine, problem is i need to access to the array keys from 0 to N and i haven't figured out how

Comment: use `foreach($array as $row)`

Comment: @Hardy how is that gonna help me display it in 3 rows? if i were using a li or a div it's ok but the table structure it's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and a counter.

```
$key = 0;
for( $i=0; $i<$rows; $i++ ) {
 <tr>  
    for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
      if ( array_key_exists( $key, $array ) ) {
         <td>echo $array[$key]</td>  // if the index is in the array print the column
      }
    }
 </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
foreach($array as $val)) {

  echo '<div class="col-md-4">' . $val . '</div>';    

}
```

If your site "grid" has 12 cols, you can just use classes like `col-sm-4`, `col-md-4` etc. to split your elements into 3 columns. Check the bootstrap manual for more info:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Can't change the layout, if i could this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but the logic is something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $a)
{
    if($i == 0 || $i % 3 == 0)
    {
        if ($i % 3 == 0)
        {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . $a . "</td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Your are missing first starting <tr>

Comment: @Hardy really ? It starts with $i = 0, and then enter the first if where I echo the "<tr>".